# Issue with using extract() PHP

Tags: php, arrays, extract

I have dynamically created an array and I want to extract the array and put each item into its own variable.

Here's my PHP:

```
$bar = $_POST['foo'];
extract($bar);
echo $1;
```

foo is an array from a form I made.

Whenever I run the script I get this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '1' (T_LNUMBER), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or '$' in /Application/...
```

When I change my code to:

```
$bar = $_POST['foo'];
extract($bar, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, "bar_");
echo $bar_1;
```

I get the undefined variable error.

Please help me.

**UPDATE:**

My first code was informational, another person might come across this question with that problem not knowing what's wrong. The second piece of code is my actual code.

M intention is to input each array item into a different field in a mysql table. I haven't written the full code yet since this extract() thing doesn't seem to be working.

**UPDATE 2:**

$_POST['foo'] is an array of checkbox values

Comment: Shows us a complete block of code so we can see the actual intentions :P

Comment: What is in there to start with? `var_dump($_POST);`

Comment: Please read the warning on [php.net](http://us2.php.net/extract#refsect1-function.extract-notes): **Do not use `extract()` on untrusted data (i.e. `$_GET`, `$_FILES`, etc.)**.

Comment: @JuanBonnett my actual intentions are to input each array item into a field in a mysql database. I haven't written the full code yet since the extract() function doesn't seem to be working

Comment: And those items are Form Fields sent by Post, right? each item has it's name, right? Edit your question and show me the form so I can see what kind of data it is sending by POST

Comment: @JuanBonnett The form is submitting an array of checkbox values

Answer (score 1):

Variables in PHP cannot start with numbers:

```
echo $1;
```

That's invalid and will throw an error.

You're also using extract improperly in that you're using it on something that may or may not be an array. We have no guarantee that $_POST['foo'] is an associative array(and it's not), which is the only array type extract works on. extract uses the keys from the associative array to create the new variables.

Comment: I know that, thats why I added EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, "bar_" to the extract function

Comment: I've answered both of your questions above.

Comment: @Zarathuztra that seems to be the problem, $_POST is an array $_POST['foo'] cannot be an array, unless its a serie of items separated by comas and then you can use explode()

Comment: @JuanBonnett - `$_POST['foo']` definitely *can* be an array. This is a perfectly valid html `name` attribute: `name="foo[]"`.

Comment: @JuanBonnett It's possible for $_POST['foo'] to be an array, such as if there are checkbox elements with the name "name[]" in the POST global, but even those aren't associative.

Comment: Completely forgot about that, even when I use it everyday for checkboxes and so..., my bad, such a silly mistake haha

Comment: @JuanBonnett $_POST['foo'] is in fact an array of checkbox values.

Comment: @JuanBonnett I say crap like that all the time, no worries. OP: It's still a numerically indexed array, it's not associative, which is required by extract()

Comment: @Zarathuztra Shouldn't EXTR_PREFIX_ALL add a prefix to all the array items?

Comment: @user3112869 Yes, to all the keys in the associative array that isn't being passed.

Answer (score 1):

```
$bar = $_POST['foo'];
extract($bar, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, "bar_");
echo $bar_1;
```

From http://php.net/extract

> *Prefixes are automatically separated from the array key by an underscore character.*

Your extracted variable is named `$bar__1` (*two* underscores).

But listen to everyone who answered, "**do not use extract() on untrusted data**."
This is very unsafe.
**You should not do it**.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($_POST['foo'] as $key=>$value) {
    ${"itemnumber".(string)$key} = $value;
}
```

Now you can acces $itemnumber2 ---> equals to the array item in the position 2

EDIT: I just tested it at writecodeonline.com and it works:

```
$arr = array('one', 'two');

foreach($arr as $key=>$value) {
    ${"itemnumber".(string)$key} = $value;
}

echo $itemnumber1; //echoes: two
```

Comment: The checkbox array won't be associative, it'll be numeric.

Comment: But check, I am using variable variables

Answer (score 0):

Here you can see a similar case:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php#60946